# Writing to txt file without separator between lines

Tags: r, write.table

I have the following dataframe (data6):

```
1   41595370       1    1   OV1

2   41595371       1    1   OV2

3   41595282       1    1   OV3

4   41595282       2    1   OV3
```

I would like to write it to txt file that all of the lines are in one line like this (i.e. no space separator between each row and space between each column):

41595370 1 1 OV141595371 1 1 OV241595282 1 1 OV341595282 2 1 OV3

When I use the following command:

```
write.table(data6, "C:/MyData.txt", eol="", quote=F)
```

I get it with spaces between each row/ line) like this:
41595370 1 1 OV1 41595371 1 1 OV2 41595282 1 1 OV3 41595282 2 1 OV3
How can I omit the space between each row/ line?

Comment: PLease don't post the same question twice.  Edit your original post as needed.

Comment: did you checked the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed with:

```
cat(paste(apply(t(df), 2, paste, collapse=' '),collapse=''), file='blob.txt')
#[1] "41595370 1 1 OV141595371 1 1 OV241595282 1 1 OV341595282 2 1 OV3"
```

Comment: Works Great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: if an answer suits you , do not forget to tick the answer so as to close the topic!